# Usage of NHibernate session after exception on query

Tags: nhibernate, azure

We are trying to implement retry logic to recover from transient errors in Azure environment.

We are using [long-running sessions](http://suryagaddipati.wordpress.com/2008/02/15/hibernate-rich-clients-and-long-running-sessions/) to keep track and commit the whole bunch of changes at the end of application transaction (which may spread over several web-requests). Along the way we need to get additional data from database. Our main problem is that we can't easily recover from db error because we can't "replay" all user actions.

So far we used straightforward recovery algorithm:

- Try to perform operation in long-running session
- In case of error, close the session, open a new one and merge entities into it
- Retry the operation

It's very expensive approach in terms of time (merge is really long for big entity hierarchies). So we'd like to optimize things a little.

We'd like to perform query operations in separate session (to keep long running one untouched and safe) and on success, merge results back to the long-running session. Retry is relatively simple here - we just need to open new session and run query once more. However, with this approach we have an issue with initializing lazy properties/collections:

- If we do this in separate session, we need to merge results back (a lot of entities) but merge could fail and break the long-running session
- We tried different ways of "moving" original entity to different session, loading details and returning it back, but without success (evict, replicate, etc.)

There is known [statement](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) that session should be discarded in case of exception. However, the example shows *write* operation. Is it still true for *read* ones? I mean if I guarantee that no data is written back to the database, can I reuse the same session to run query again?

Do you have any other suggestions about retry logic with long-running sessions?

Comment: i once implemented a IDBCommand wrapper injected with IConnectionProvider and IDBConnection which implemented a retry for ExecuteReader, ExecuteScalar, ExecuteNonQuery. Maybe you could try so too

Comment: Thanks for reply.
How you handled transactions that contain multiple db commands? If we will inject retry logic on connection and commands level that would affect insert and update operations. Is it sufficient to retry separate command instead of the whole transaction?
It seems that NH handles different actions(Update, Insert, Delete) in different requests so Azure could reject command in the middle of transaction.

Comment: the best you can do is simulating it, but i would say it is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there's no way to solve your issue. It's gonna take a lot of time to commit everything or you will have to do a lot of work to break it up into smaller sessions and handle every error that can occur while merging.

To answer your question about using the session after an exception: you cannot trust ANYTHING anymore inside this session, not even loaded entities.

Read this paragraph from Ayende's [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) about building a simple todo app with a recoveryplan in case of an exception in the session:

> Then there is the problem of error handling. If you get an exception
>   (such as StaleObjectStateException, because of concurrency conflict),
>   your session and its loaded entities are toast, because with
>   NHibernate, an exception thrown from a session moves that session into
>   an undefined state. You can no longer use that session or any loaded
>   entities. If you have only a single global session, it means that you
>   probably need to restart the application, which is probably not a good
>   idea.